# Trying to get data from SQLite DB using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite

I'm trying to extract data from the SQLite database using NodeJS following the [tutorial](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-nodejs/query/) Following @ShadowCode answer I modified my code as follows.

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3').verbose();

//open the database
let db = new sqlite3.Database('src/assets/academia.db');

db.run("SELECT userid as id, firstname, lastname FROM users", function(err, row){
    console.log(row.userid + " " + row.firstname + " " + row.lastname);
});

//close connection
db.close();
```

I get an error saying it can't read property userID. If I run the sql statement in database it runs perfectly.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userid' of undefined
    at Statement.<anonymous> (C:\academia_2\src\get.js:7:21)
--> in Database#run('SELECT userid, firstname, lastname FROM users', [Function])
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your Tutorial is kinda outdated, maybe take a look at the docs
[sqlite3 - npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sqlite3).

Look at this Snippet, for me it worked.

```
db.run("UPDATE tbl SET name = ? WHERE id = ?", "bar", 2);
```

Comment: Thanks I'll take look.